# How to select a node in HtmlAgilityPack alter the nodetext using xpath function and return the node with the modifiied string

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

Basically, I want to select a node. So when I retrieve its innertText property I get the modified text of that node. The idea is that the text is modified by xpath functions such as substring, ceiling, etc.. I hope you understand. Note: I don't want to modify the returned text with C# functions I want that the content is modified with xpath and then just grabbed by C#.

Comment: you can't modify content with XPath - XPath is for *selecting* a bunch of nodes, not for modifying them

Comment: So what's the point of having XSLT functions such as substring, replace, etc? And I am able to use them in HAP.

Answer (score 0):

XPath have not functions to edit text. You can use Regex to edit the text. first - pharse the html page with XPath, after that - clean the text, edit it by Regex.